# Minified jQueryUI for Tooltip Mouse Tracking

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

Does anyone know how to make this tooltip mouse tracking work by using minified files? I had include these files in the page, but it didn't work.

- jquery.ui.core.min.js
- jquery.ui.widget.min.js
- jquery.ui.position.min.js
- jquery.ui.tooltip.min.js
- http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

I downloaded all minified files from this link [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/msc-ito-project-0910/source/browse/trunk/hrr/jquery/ui/minified/?r=272).

Comment: show your code or fiddle here .

Answer (score 0):

**Taken directly from [the documentation](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#tracking):**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).tooltip({
            track: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-track